# Problem with the optional value of the first argument of a newcommand

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%définition de variable texte pour compilation conditionnelle
\def\ChoixDeVersion{AB} %AB=Avec Barème, SB ou autre = sans bareme

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\bareme}[1][2 ]{%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\ChoixDeVersion}{AB}}%
     {#1 AB \ignorespaces}%
     {#1 \ignorespaces}%
}     
\begin{document}
\bareme{123 } 
\end{document}
```

The optional value of the first argument of the command `\bareme` is displayed all the time even if i give an argument when I call the command

`\bareme{123 }` gives

[image]

I would espect  `123 AB`. The value of the argument when I call the command (123) should take the place of the optional value (2 ) of the first argument (#1).

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: If there is just one (optional) argument, shouldn't it be `\bareme[123 ]`?

Comment: I give first the number of argument `[1]` and then the default value of the first arguement `[2]` (`2 is the default value`). For me `\bareme[123 ]` would mean 123 arguments for the command `\bareme`

Comment: Ahhh you mean for the call. Sounds strange to me, but that gives the result. Thank you so much.

Comment: Strange? The syntax for optional argument has always been with brackets `[...]`, not with braces `{...}`

Comment: Would it be possibe to make change(s) in a way to ge the value by `\bareme{value}` ?  I would like to have the same syntaxe with the value `\bareme{value}`and default value `\bareme{}`

Comment: @Idefix: You can get this weird behaviour with `xparse` and its `g` specifier for macro arguments

Comment: @Idefix Why would you break a 30 year old convention? Just in order to confuse your coworkers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't recommend the misuse of the `g` or `G` optional argument specifier as `{}` usage.

LaTeX has only `[]` as optional argument for `\newcommand` etc. With `g` or `G` from `xparse` (which uses `expl3` as 'upcoming' format of LaTeX 3) it is possible to apply `\NewDocumentCommand` and provide `G{2}` as optional argument that can be used with `{}` instead of `[]` -- `2` is the default value of the argument if it is not specified at all.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

%définition de variable texte pour compilation conditionnelle
\def\ChoixDeVersion{AB} %AB=Avec Barème, SB ou autre = sans bareme

\usepackage{ifthen}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bareme}{G{2}}{%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\ChoixDeVersion}{AB}}%
     {#1 AB \ignorespaces}%
     {#1 \ignorespaces}%
}     
\begin{document}
\bareme{123} 

\bareme
\end{document}
```

[image]